# Failing under Correct VS Setup: Cannot open include file: 'imgui.h'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, imgui

I beleive I am setting up my VS Config correctly but I still get errors when including a file as follows:
[image: Failure to include Iimgui]

The imgui file is under:
[image: imgui folder]

The error is:
[image: error message]

**Could you please help me?**

Comment: Your settings look correct for the Debug configuration. Remember each configuration has independent settings. Where is your project file in relation to the vendors folder? Your redaction makes it more difficult to help.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I have followed the same approach with other vendors and it works. This definitly something alse other than folder's path, but I will try to include all info asap.

Comment: To confirm I include the imgui as a static library. Could that be it, should I use dynamic linkage?

Comment: I have made an answer. If you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to link static library, I suggest you to read this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) carefully.